# Metro UI shortcuts in Win8 - how to move multiple shortcuts to desktop?

Tags: windows-8

If a user installs a traditional win7 app in win8, the shortcut appears on the metro UI.  This is sometimes not desired. How can a user move multiple shortcuts (e.g., all 15 accumulated there) quickly from metro to the desktop?

What is the folder where desktop shortcuts are?
Is the metro UI organized similarly and user can hack into a similar folder for the metro UI?

Then it would be a simple move operation.

Answer (score 2):

- Right click to select *one* of the Start Screen icons and choose `Open File Location` from the bottom bar.
- This will open Explorer to where the shortcut is (probably in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\...`).
- Select and Cut the shortcut(s) you want to move.
- Navigate to your desktop.
- Paste them.
- Repeat as required for additional icons.

Comment: hmm. It is not so simple. Shortcut links seem to be in subfolders and there are links that do not display on metro. Perhaps a dedicated software for this is better.